# how to get the filename of all token words in hadoop WordCount app?

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, mapreduce

In WordCount task in hadoop, How to get the filename of the token word and use it in context.write(new Test(filename), one)?

Answer (score 1):

The file name can be retrieved using the below code snippet in Mapper class.

```
FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit)context.getInputSplit();
String filename = fileSplit.getPath().getName();
```

Comment: Hi Madhu, Do you know how to send file name as a value when using context.write. In the example WordCount, I want to use context.write(new Text(stringWord), fileName); instead of context.write(new Text(stringWord), one); I have made some changes in reduce part but still not working.

Comment: can you post your full code?... If you are not passing one then how we will be able to find the word count... can you let me know clearly

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32969870/wordcount-example-with-count-per-file/32970219#32970219